# Trying to "iterate" a folder

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, do-while

I'm not sure if I'm using the right word: I'm trying to "iterate" trought a folder of files using Do While

My failed attempt:

```
    Sub Main()

    Dim myurl As String
    Dim m As Object
    myurl = "\\myroute\myroute"
    ChDir(myurl)
    m = Dir(myurl)

    Do While m <> ""  '<--m = nothing?

        ...'lines not important here

    Loop

End Sub
```

But for some reason, when I start debugging, m has no value(m=nothing) so "do while" bucle is ignored.
What am I doing wrong? Any idea how to do it? 
  "\myroute\myroute" does exists

Comment: What language are you really using? vb.net and VBA are very different platforms.

Comment: Is this VB.Net or excel VBA? You have it tagged for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very helpful method in .NET to do this [Directory.EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458.aspx):

```
For Each fileName As String In Directory.EnumerateFiles(myDirectory)
    ' Add your code
Next
```

You have to import the `System.IO` namespace to use the `Directory` class:

```
Imports System.IO
```